# Recursive polynomial

Tags: c

I'm working on calculation of Legendre Polynomial on GPU.

Briefly, Recursive Legendre Polynomial is computing the n-th order by (n-1)th and (n-2)th order. We divide the `x` into `k` (let's say k=23) parts to compute polynomial and do a summation, which would be more precise.

So my kernel goes below.

1. First, we create a `k * width` array.

```
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float delta = 2. / width;
    if ((row < d_k) && (col < width)) 
        kXList[row * width + col] = -1.f + (col * d_k + row + 1.f) * delta / (float)d_k;
```

2. And 1st order and 2nd order, `kXList_2` is the first, `kXList_1` is the second.

```
    kXList_1[row * width + col] = kXList[row * width + col];
    kXList_2[row * width + col] = 1.f;
```

3. Do summation over columns and saving it into `d_xLegendreP`.

```
        if (row == 0) {
            float row_0 = 0.f;
            float row_1 = 0.f;
            for (int h = 0; h < d_k; ++h) {
                row_0 += kXList_2[h * width + col];
                row_1 += kXList_1[h * width + col];
            }
            d_xLegendreP[0 * width + col] = row_0;
            d_xLegendreP[1 * width + col] = row_1;
        }
```

4. recusive calculation of rest order.

```
        float kX_2 = kXList_2[row * width + col];
        float kX_1 = kXList_1[row * width + col];
        float kX = kXList[row * width + col];
        float row_n;
        for (int n = 2; n <= order; n++) {
            kXList_temp[row * width + col] = ((2.f * n - 1.f) * kX * kX_1) / (float)n - (((n - 1.f) * kX_2) / (float)n);
            if ((row == 0)) {
                row_n = 0.f;
                for (int h = 0; h < d_k; h++) {
                    row_n += kXList_temp[h * width + col];
                }
                d_xLegendreP[n * width + col] = row_n;
            }
            kX_2 = kX_1;
            kX_1 = kXList_temp[row * width + col];
        }
```

Comment: As was pointed out in comments on your previous question about this, you cannot expect the summation over columns to work as you have written it. That operation implicitly requires that all threads have completed the column entries before it can be performed correctly, and that implies synchronization which CUDA may or may not be able to provide unless you do something like split the phases of calculations into separate kernels with synchronization between them

Comment: @talonmies, thanks, it may works. I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, CUDA makes no statements about the order of thread execution.  However you have a number of points in your calculation sequence where you expect a previous line of code has been completed in its entirety, across the entire grid, in order for the next section of your code to be correct.

Generally the nature of CUDA parallel thread execution means that such dependencies lead to incorrect/broken code.

I haven't tried to fully realize your algorithm in an optimal way, but to demonstrate the proof of this, I have broken up your kernel code in such a way that such dependencies are made "correct" through the use of the kernel-call boundary, which is effectively a global sync.  This is probably one way to sort out your problem, as indicated in the comments.

Here's an example.  I'm not going to try to detail each change, but by breaking it up this way I believe I have satisfied the dependencies expected using your approach.  I have not fully verified anything, but a quick check suggests the output seems to match your matlab output:

```
$ cat t1820.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define BLOCKDIM_32     32

#define k               23
#define Mmax            40
#define IMG_SIZE        1024

static const long DEVICE = 0;

#define CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char* file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

__global__ void LegendreMoment1(float* kXList, float* kXList_1, float* kXList_2, float* kXList_temp,
    float* d_xLegendreP, int width, int d_k, int order) {
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float delta = 2. / width;
    if ((row < d_k) && (col < width)) {
        kXList[row * width + col] = -1.f + (col * d_k + row + 1.f) * delta / (float)d_k;
        kXList_1[row * width + col] = kXList[row * width + col];
        kXList_2[row * width + col] = 1.f;
        }
}
__global__ void LegendreMoment2(float* kXList, float* kXList_1, float* kXList_2, float* kXList_temp,
    float* d_xLegendreP, int width, int d_k, int order) {
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if ((row < d_k) && (col < width)) {
        if (row == 0) {
            float row_0 = 0.f;
            float row_1 = 0.f;
            for (int h = 0; h < d_k; ++h) {
                row_0 += kXList_2[h * width + col];
                row_1 += kXList_1[h * width + col];
            }
            d_xLegendreP[0 * width + col] = row_0;
            d_xLegendreP[1 * width + col] = row_1;
        }
    }
}
__global__ void LegendreMoment3(float* kXList, float* kXList_1, float* kXList_2, float* kXList_temp,
    float* d_xLegendreP, int width, int d_k, int order, int n, float *kXList_prev) {
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if ((row < d_k) && (col < width)) {
        float kX_2, kX_1, kX = kXList[row * width + col];
        if (n == 2){
          kX_2 = kXList_2[row * width + col];
          kX_1 = kXList_1[row * width + col];}
        if (n == 3){
          kX_2 = kXList_1[row * width + col];
          kX_1 = kXList_temp[row*width+col];}
        if (n > 3){
          kX_2 = kXList_prev[row * width + col];
          kX_1 = kXList_temp[row*width+col];}
        kXList_prev[row*width+col] = kX_1;
        kXList_temp[row * width + col] = ((2.f * n - 1.f) * kX * kX_1) / (float)n - (((n - 1.f) * kX_2) / (float)n);
    }
}
__global__ void LegendreMoment4(float* kXList, float* kXList_1, float* kXList_2, float* kXList_temp,
    float* d_xLegendreP, int width, int d_k, int order, int n) {
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float row_n;
    if ((row < d_k) && (col < width)) {
            if ((row == 0)) {
                row_n = 0.f;
                for (int h = 0; h < d_k; h++) {
                    row_n += kXList_temp[h * width + col];
                }
                d_xLegendreP[n * width + col] = row_n;
            }
    }
}

float matlab_result[][4] = {
 {23., 23., 23., 23.},
 {-22.9766, -22.9316, -22.8867, -22.8418},
 {22.9297, 22.7952, 22.661, 22.527},
 {-22.8596, -22.5914, -22.3245, -22.059},
 {22.7663, 22.3211, 21.8799, 21.4425},
 {-22.6501, -21.9856, -21.3303, -20.6839},
 {22.5111, 21.5864, 20.6798, 19.7912},
 {-22.3496, -21.1254, -19.9335, -18.7734},
 {22.166, 20.6046, 19.0967, 17.6411},
 {-21.9606, -20.0265, -18.1756, -16.4058},
 {21.7339, 19.3937, 17.1772, 15.0802},
 {-21.4862, -18.7091, -16.1086, -13.6777},
 {21.2181, 17.9757, 14.9778, 12.2124},
 {-20.9301, -17.1971, -13.7931, -10.6992},
 {20.6228, 16.3766, 12.563, 9.15308},
 {-20.2967, -15.5179, -11.2963, -7.5893},
 {19.9525, 14.625, 10.0023, 6.02321},
 {-19.5909, -13.7018, -8.69016, -4.46998},
 {19.2126, 12.7524, 7.36912, 2.94447},
 {-18.8183, -11.781, -6.04847, -1.46107},
 {18.4087, 10.792, 4.73739, 0.0335239},
 {-17.9847, -9.78953, -3.44488, 1.32519},
 {17.5472, 8.77808, 2.17971, -2.60304},
 {-17.0968, -7.76199, -0.950332, 3.78904},
 {16.6345, 6.74559, -0.235176, -4.87336},
 {-16.1611, -5.7332, 1.36917, 5.84745},
 {15.6776, 4.72908, -2.44452, -6.70411},
 {-15.1848, -3.73739, 3.45463, 7.43756},
 {14.6836, 2.7622, -4.39351, -8.04346},
 {-14.1751, -1.80747, 5.25583, 8.51902},
 {13.66, 0.877003, -6.03692, -8.86292},
 {-13.1395, 0.0255473, 6.73284, 9.07537},
 {12.6143, -0.896704, -7.34039, -9.15805},
 {-12.0855, 1.73318, 7.85712, 9.11411},
 {11.554, -2.53191, -8.28135, -8.94808},
 {-11.0207, 3.29003, 8.61218, 8.6658},
 {10.4866, -4.00492, -8.84949, -8.27433},
 {-9.95254, 4.67419, 8.99391, 7.78188},
 {9.41953, -5.29574, -9.04682, -7.19767},
 {-8.88843, 5.8677, 9.01035, 6.53179},
 {8.36015, -6.38847, -8.88731, -5.79509}
};
#define TOL 0.0001f

int main()
{
    float* kXList;
    float* kXList_1;
    float* kXList_2;
    float* kXList_temp;
    float* kXList_prev;
    float* d_xLegendreP;
    float* xLegendreP;

    int width = IMG_SIZE;

    cudaEvent_t d_total_begin, d_total_end;

    xLegendreP = new float[(Mmax + 1) * width];
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaSetDevice(DEVICE));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaEventCreate(&d_total_begin));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaEventCreate(&d_total_end));


    printf("Time kernel launch...\n");
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaEventRecord(d_total_begin, 0));

    printf("Allocating space on device...\n");

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(
        cudaMalloc((void**)&kXList, width * k * sizeof(float)));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(
        cudaMalloc((void**)&kXList_temp, width * k * sizeof(float)));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(
        cudaMalloc((void**)&kXList_prev, width * k * sizeof(float)));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(
        cudaMalloc((void**)&kXList_1, width * k * sizeof(float)));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(
        cudaMalloc((void**)&kXList_2, width * k * sizeof(float)));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(
        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_xLegendreP, width * (Mmax + 1) * sizeof(float)));

    printf("Copying data from host to device...\n");

    dim3 grid(ceil(Mmax / 32), ceil(width / 32), 1);
    dim3 block(BLOCKDIM_32, BLOCKDIM_32, 1);

    printf("Launching kernel...\n");
    LegendreMoment1 << <grid, block >> > (kXList, kXList_1, kXList_2, kXList_temp,
        d_xLegendreP, IMG_SIZE, k, Mmax);
    LegendreMoment2 << <grid, block >> > (kXList, kXList_1, kXList_2, kXList_temp,
        d_xLegendreP, IMG_SIZE, k, Mmax);
    for (int n = 2; n <= Mmax; n++) {
      LegendreMoment3 << <grid, block >> > (kXList, kXList_1, kXList_2, kXList_temp,
        d_xLegendreP, IMG_SIZE, k, Mmax, n, kXList_prev);
      LegendreMoment4 << <grid, block >> > (kXList, kXList_1, kXList_2, kXList_temp,
        d_xLegendreP, IMG_SIZE, k, Mmax, n);
      }
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(
        cudaMemcpy(xLegendreP, d_xLegendreP, width * (Mmax + 1) * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaEventRecord(d_total_end, 0));

    printf("\n");
    for (int n = 0; n <= Mmax; n++)
            printf("row %2d:%8.4f %8.4f %8.4f %8.4f\n", n, xLegendreP[n * width + 0],xLegendreP[n * width + 1],xLegendreP[n * width + 2],xLegendreP[n * width + 3]);

    for (int i = 0; i < Mmax; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        if (fabsf(xLegendreP[i*width+j] - matlab_result[i][j]) > TOL) {printf("mismatch at %d, %d\n", i, j); return 0;}
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaEventSynchronize(d_total_end));
    float gpuTime = 0.0;
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaEventElapsedTime(&gpuTime, d_total_begin, d_total_end));

    printf(">>>Elapsed GPU Time is : %f ms\n", gpuTime);

    printf("Freeing memory on device...\n");
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaEventDestroy(d_total_begin));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaEventDestroy(d_total_end));

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaFree(kXList));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaFree(kXList_temp));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaFree(kXList_1));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaFree(kXList_2));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaFree(d_xLegendreP));
    printf("Exiting program...\n");
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1820 t1820.cu
$ ./t1820
Time kernel launch...
Allocating space on device...
Copying data from host to device...
Launching kernel...

row  0: 23.0000  23.0000  23.0000  23.0000
row  1:-22.9766 -22.9316 -22.8867 -22.8418
row  2: 22.9297  22.7952  22.6610  22.5270
row  3:-22.8596 -22.5914 -22.3245 -22.0590
row  4: 22.7663  22.3211  21.8799  21.4425
row  5:-22.6501 -21.9856 -21.3303 -20.6839
row  6: 22.5111  21.5864  20.6798  19.7912
row  7:-22.3496 -21.1254 -19.9335 -18.7734
row  8: 22.1660  20.6046  19.0967  17.6411
row  9:-21.9606 -20.0265 -18.1756 -16.4058
row 10: 21.7339  19.3937  17.1772  15.0802
row 11:-21.4862 -18.7090 -16.1086 -13.6777
row 12: 21.2181  17.9757  14.9778  12.2124
row 13:-20.9301 -17.1971 -13.7931 -10.6992
row 14: 20.6228  16.3766  12.5630   9.1531
row 15:-20.2967 -15.5179 -11.2963  -7.5893
row 16: 19.9525  14.6250  10.0023   6.0232
row 17:-19.5909 -13.7018  -8.6902  -4.4700
row 18: 19.2126  12.7524   7.3691   2.9445
row 19:-18.8183 -11.7810  -6.0485  -1.4611
row 20: 18.4087  10.7920   4.7374   0.0335
row 21:-17.9848  -9.7895  -3.4449   1.3252
row 22: 17.5472   8.7781   2.1797  -2.6030
row 23:-17.0968  -7.7620  -0.9503   3.7890
row 24: 16.6345   6.7456  -0.2352  -4.8734
row 25:-16.1611  -5.7332   1.3692   5.8475
row 26: 15.6776   4.7291  -2.4445  -6.7041
row 27:-15.1848  -3.7374   3.4546   7.4376
row 28: 14.6836   2.7622  -4.3935  -8.0435
row 29:-14.1751  -1.8075   5.2558   8.5190
row 30: 13.6600   0.8770  -6.0369  -8.8629
row 31:-13.1395   0.0255   6.7328   9.0754
row 32: 12.6143  -0.8967  -7.3404  -9.1581
row 33:-12.0855   1.7332   7.8571   9.1141
row 34: 11.5540  -2.5319  -8.2813  -8.9481
row 35:-11.0207   3.2900   8.6122   8.6658
row 36: 10.4866  -4.0049  -8.8495  -8.2743
row 37: -9.9525   4.6742   8.9939   7.7819
row 38:  9.4195  -5.2957  -9.0468  -7.1977
row 39: -8.8884   5.8677   9.0103   6.5318
row 40:  8.3601  -6.3885  -8.8873  -5.7951
>>>Elapsed GPU Time is : 1.223776 ms
Freeing memory on device...
Exiting program...
$
```

I'm not suggesting the above code is defect-free or suitable for any particular purpose.  It is mostly your code.  I've made some changes to demonstrate the need for global sync that is inherent in your approach.

Comment: Thanks, Robert, Your answer is amazing!